# Element TextViewCompat is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, textview

I'm trying to use TextViewCompat on my app to support older android versions according this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) from Android Documentation.

But I'm facing this waring on Android Studio:

> Element TextViewCompat is not allowed here
>   This inspection highlights unallowed XML tags in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.841"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />

    <TextViewCompat
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        android:text="10 min"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this to take advantage of `AppCompatTextView`, as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView):

> This will automatically be used when you use TextView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Basically, when you build your app, appcompat swaps out instances of various UI widgets in XML for the Compat version. As long as you aren't extending a widget, you don't need to worry about this behavior (and you'll get a lint warning telling you what to do if you do want to extend widgets).

You only need `TextViewCompat` if you try to manipulate the auto-sizing APIs programmatically from Java/Kotlin. This is done by finding the view as a `TextView`, and then using static methods on `TextViewCompat`:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textview, myTextSizeType);
```

Comment: right, i agree but when i try to follow documentation using this piece of code TextViewCompat textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2); textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM); give me another error, please see: https://imgur.com/a/wOHyH4u

Comment: @Nakamoto - this happens because TextViewCompat is not a subclass of View. It is a direct subclass of Object. The method `findViewById()` will try to return a View. If it does find any View by the given id then it will try to cast it to the class to which the variable (textView) belongs. This is not possible (Java rules), so you get an error

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm new on Android but I've understood you. But how can I find the View on Layout programatically? Should I use only on xml or on code? What should I do ?

Comment: @Nakamoto - Just do like emersso says: use TextView in layouts and code. TextViewCompat is just a helper class like e.g. Math . TextViewCompat offers useful methods for dealing with TextViews but it is not a TextView, just like Math is not a number.

Comment: I'll amend the answer on how to interact with the view programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.TextViewCompat` or  `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`

Comment: Thanks man! But why does it's not specified on official documentation? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: I don't want to confuse you. See my edited answer. You can use any of the 2. I use the 2nd

Comment: both works but I can't use android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" on my layout. And this feature is supported to older versions according documentation

Comment: If you want this feature use `setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(int autoSizeTextType)`, see this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

Comment: giving another error ` TextViewCompat textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM); `

See here: https://imgur.com/a/wOHyH4u

Comment: I would suggest to use `AppCompatTextView` or just plain `TextView`

Comment: Even using TextView, give me another compile error. I guess I'll try ask another question

Comment: Just remove TextViewCompat if the error persists and use `AppCompatTextView` or just plain `TextView` in xml and `TextView` in code

Comment: mTak I've found! it give an error using android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" instead of APP:autoSizeTextType="uniform" after change this, error disappears, really thanks man!

Comment: sorry my confusion too!

Comment: I get `Binary XML file line #105: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.TextViewCompat` with this code.